# Unable to Sign PowerShell Scripts

Tags: powershell

I can't seem to get my scripts to sign in PowerShell. I have a valid code signing cert installed on my machine and run the following commands. Any suggestions?

```
PS C:\Users\u00\bin> $cert = @(Get-ChildItem cert:\CurrentUser\My -codesigning)[0]
PS C:\Users\u00\bin> $cert | fl


Subject      : E=operations@contoso.com, CN=contoso , OU=Operations, O=contoso,
               L=Mayberry, S=Florida, C=US
Issuer       : CN=contoso Intermediate CA1, DC=contoso, DC=com
Thumbprint   : XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
FriendlyName : contoso 
NotBefore    : 7/20/2010 12:58:55 AM
NotAfter     : 7/20/2011 12:58:55 AM
Extensions   : {System.Security.Cryptography.Oid, System.Security.Cryptography.Oid, System.Security.Cryptography.Oi
               ystem.Security.Cryptography.Oid...}



PS C:\Users\u00\bin> Set-AuthenticodeSignature .\testsign.ps1 -Certificate $cert


    Directory: C:\Users\u00\bin


SignerCertificate                         Status                                 Path
-----------------                         ------                                 ----
                                          UnknownError                           testsign.ps1


PS C:\Users\u00\bin> Get-AuthenticodeSignature .\testsign.ps1

    Directory: C:\Users\u00\bin


SignerCertificate                         Status                                 Path
-----------------                         ------                                 ----
                                          NotSigned                              testsign.ps1
```

Comment: Good to know.  I was taking a look at your question because I can't sign my scripts either, without being an Administrator on the PC.  I asked about it here: http://superuser.com/questions/174878/powershell-access-denied-to-cert-currentuser-my

Comment: Good question and thanks for posting back the answer. You should go ahead and post your edit in the answer section and then after the timeout mark it as correct so people can more clearly see this question has been answered.

Comment: I had a similar issue trying to use Subversion when editing scripts in the ISE.  Subversion complained that the files saved by the ISE were 'binary mime-type' and wouldn't add them to the repository.  I've posted a smoother workaround to the Notepad.exe approach in my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out. The script file was created using PowerShell ISE and apparently you [can't sign scripts created in PowerShell ISE](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/483431/set-authenticodesignature-fails-on-scripts-created-from-ise) or more accurately you can't sign Unicode Big Endian encoded files which is the default for ISE. There's workaround to change the default encoding as documented in link.

---

Originally added to question by [Chad Miller](https://serverfault.com/users/7934/chad-miller).  Relocated his update to an answer so this question no longer shows up as unanswered.

Comment: Good to know - that Unicode file encoding issue has bitten me elsewhere (a badly written XML parser).

Comment: And me the other day when writing a script to export MS-DHCP leases for BIND DHCP. Unicode again.

Answer (score 3):

You can save a file as a specific encoding from within the Powershell ISE with the .Save() method of the ISEFile object:

```
 $psIse.CurrentFile.Save([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8)
```

If you add the following to your ISE profile you can just hit Ctrl-Shift-S to get a different default encoding for your scripts:

```
$psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab.AddOnsMenu.SubMenus.Add("_Save as UTF8",{$psIse.CurrentFile.Save([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8)},"Ctrl+Shift+S")
```

Here's some quickie code to create your profile if it doesn't exist and add the menu.  Run this code from within the ISE or you'll just add junk to your ConsoleHost profile where it will just error out:

```
add-content $profile -value '$psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab.AddOnsMenu.SubMenus.Add("_Save as UTF8",{$psIse.CurrentFile.Save([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8)},"Ctrl+Shift+S")'
```